# Add token to src tag requests Angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular, asp.net-core

I'm creating an website where users can load another website i'm developing after logging in. When authorized, the users gets a JWT token, and this token is sent in the header with every request, just like any webapplication with JWT token authorization.

The problem is that I only want to send the sensitive page content to the user that is authorized. The authorization in the backend is already working with normal API calls, but I can't intercept calls made by the system itself when encountering a "src" tag for example.

The HTML file is requested like this (for convenience the header token is added here instead of in a seperate interceptor file):

```
redirect(response) {
    console.log(response);

    if(response.isAdmin) {
      const headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", "Bearer " + response.token);

      this.http.get("AdminPage", {headers: headers, responseType: "text"}).subscribe(response => {
        // response is the HTML file
        const win = window.open("", "_self");
        win.document.documentElement.innerHTML = response;
      });
    } else {
      // The users page will be loaded here just like above, with another path
      // TODO
    }
  }
```

The HTML file is loaded, but when it encounters the "src" tags in it, it will request the files from the server, but the server won't respond because there is no JWT token in the request.

Is there any way to intercept this calls too? Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

(I don't know if its relevant, but my backend is written in ASPNET.Core)

Comment: If you store the JWT as a cookie then it will be sent with each request inherently. Then you don't need to add it to each request that you're making. The backend would then just use the JWT value stored in the cookie.

Comment: Great idea! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it as Get parameter like that

```html
<img src="http://img.com?token=<token>"/>
```

Or you can use cookies like @matt suggested

Comment: Thank you, but then i need to modify every html page. I think the cookie anwer is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it is really easy. You can just store your JWT token inside a cookie using the following code inside the controller in the backend (in ASPNET.Core):

```
CookieOptions cookieOptions = new CookieOptions();
cookieOptions.HttpOnly = true;
Response.Cookies.Append("auth_token", user.Token, cookieOptions);
```

And you can retreive the token inside the authorization middleware like this:

```
string token = context.Request.Cookies["auth_token"];
```

It is also more secure then storing it inside local/session storage because of XSS attacks.

I've read about it here:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-working-with-cookie/

And here:

https://blog.logrocket.com/jwt-authentication-best-practices/

With the cookie, you don't even need to intercept the http request in the frontend, because the cookie is sent automatically with every request.

credits to @Matt Davis